Need software to locate sounds in mostly quite audio with some background noise
I need some software which can detect periods of sounds in audio clips, like sudden changes in the volume due to some activity, or changes in the background noise. The audio is quiet for the most part which some background noise, like passing traffic and the humming of equipment like fans etc.
The audio clips are quite long, some lasting over 24 hours.
What software can I use for this?

Bunch of audio-related sofware will have such capability, also free Audacity offers a functionality called Silence Finder, for which you can define the appriopriate levels.

